# d3.geom.quadtree is not working?

Tags: d3.js, quadtree

Code below, and then console.log. It seems that the quadtree structure is empty. Why?. My code is from example
https://www.phase2technology.com/blog/using-d3-quadtrees-to-power-an-interactive-map-for-bonnier-corporation/

```
var longlattable = [
    [23.4183, 62.7750],
    [22.0064, 62.714],
    [23.7428, 62.266],
    [23.65, 62.85],
    [23.1977778, 62.6272222],
    [23.675, 62.5236111],
];
var pointsRaw = d3.map(longlattable, function(d, i) {
    var point = d;
    console.log("thepoint", point, "iii",i);
    point.push(i);
    return point;
});

console.log("pointsraw", pointsRaw);
quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree()(pointsRaw);
console.log("quadtree00", quadtree);
```

console.log:

thepoint [23.4183, 62.775] iii 0
....

pointsraw c {*: Object}*: Object22.0064,62.714,1: Array[3]0: 22.00641: 62.7142: 1length: 3__proto__: Array[0]23.65,62.85,3: Array[3]23.675,62.5236111,5: Array[3]23.4183,62.775,0: Array[3]23.7428,62.266,2: Array[3]23.1977778,62.6272222,4: Array[3]**proto**: c

quadtree00 Object {leaf: true, nodes: Array[0], point: null, x: null, y: null}add: (n)find: (n)leaf: truenodes: Array[0]point: nullvisit: (n)x: nully: null__proto__: Object

---

So quadtree seems to be empty, but can't figure out why. Help appreciated very much, thank you.

Comment: you could have simply done like this _quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree()(longlattable);_ and it will work! ... not able to understand your logic in the d3.map function what are you trying to achieve, the logic is not clear

Comment: Thank you very much, that works. The idea is similar than in the link above. And now it work.

Comment: Btw, I realized that it is not wise to use latitude and longitude directly in the quadtree. quadtree.visit is obviously not working properly, visit arguments {node, x1, y1, x2, y2} and the rule  x1 <= x2 and y1 <= y2, top-left and bottom-right corners of the node respectively, does not apply to latitude longitude. latitude is smaller (y2 < y1) in bottom-right corner than in top-left. So the latitude longitudes should be transformed by projection method and then put into quadtree. See the documentation https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quadtree-Geom